# Como verificar elementos duplicados em array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Preciso saber se um array no JavaScript tem elementos duplicados.

Tem alguma função na API do jQuery que faz isso? Caso não, como posso proceder?

Comment: O que já tentou ? tem algum exemplo ?

Comment: O que você quer 'fazer' com os duplicados? Remover do array? Salvar em outro array? Apenas printar no console?

Comment: Talvez esta pergunta te ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99193/valor-em-array-com-a-maior-ocorr%C3%AAncia

Comment: A [Resposta está aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376160/capturar-elementos-repetidos-de-um-array-javascript), a variável vetor, é onde teria os elementos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com o magia do ES6 é possível resolver seu problema com apenas uma linha de código. Ex:

```
var a = ["Ceará","Eusébio","Ceará"];
var b = ["JavaScript",">","All"];

function hasDuplicates(array) {
    return (new Set(array)).size !== array.length;
}

hasDuplicates(a);//true
hasDuplicates(b);//false
```

Answer (score 3):

Não, não existe nenhuma função via jQuery que faça isso.. o mais próximo dessa realidade seria o [.unique()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/), porém só funciona com elementos `DOM`.

Mas você mesmo pode desenvolver seu próprio método utilizando `.each` e `.inArray`.

Dê uma olhada:

```
var times = ["Flamengo","Vasco","Corinthians","Fluminense","Corinthians","Fluminense","Palmeiras","Vasco"];
var timesNaoDuplicados = [];
$.each(times, function(i, elemento){
    if($.inArray(elemento, timesNaoDuplicados) === -1) timesNaoDuplicados.push(elemento);
});

//Se "printar" o timesNaoDuplicados: ["Flamengo", "Vasco", "Corinthians", "Fluminense", "Palmeiras"]
```

Se você quiser saber **apenas** se um *elemento* está dentro de um array, utilize o `.inArray(elemento, Array)`.

Mais sobre o `.inArray` [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Em resumo, ele te retorna a posição (index) onde o elemento está dentro do array. Se não achar nada, retorna -1.

Comment: [RESOLVIDO] O seu codigo não me atende, pois eu preciso saber quais os elementos duplicados. Então já resolvi. Achei a resposta no site :http://www.lucaspeperaio.com.br/blog/funcao-javascript-para-eliminar-duplicidade-em-array . Este retorna os elementos duplicados no array
Mas obrigado pela atenção. Segue codigo abaixo: 
<code>
Array.prototype.duplicates = function (){
    return this.filter(function(x,y,k){
        return y !== k.lastIndexOf(x) ;
    }) ;
}
var duplicados = ['a','b','c','d','a','b'].duplicates();

Comment: [RESOLVIDO] O seu codigo não me atende, pois eu preciso saber quais os elementos duplicados. Então já resolvi. Achei a resposta no site [link] (http://www.lucaspeperaio.com.br/blog/funcao-javascript-para-eliminar-duplicidade-em-array)[/link] . Este retorna os elementos duplicados no array
Mas obrigado pela atenção. Segue codigo abaixo: 
'codigo'
Array.prototype.duplicates = function (){
    return this.filter(function(x,y,k){
        return y !== k.lastIndexOf(x) ;
    }) ;
}
var duplicados = ['a','b','c','d','a','b'].duplicates();
'/codigo'

Comment: código no ideone: [retornar somente os valores duplicados de um array](https://ideone.com/sorfs9)