# Capturar elementos repetidos de um array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Preciso remover os valores repetidos de um vetor e jogar esses valores repetidos em outro vetor, encontrei esse código que remove os valores repetidos, porém não sei como faço para capturá-los, e não estou entendendo muito bem como o `filter` está agindo para remover os valores repetidos. Alguém pode me explicar com mais detalhes o que está acontecendo no código?

```
var aux = vetor.filter(function(elemento, i) {
    return vetor.indexOf(elemento) == i;
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Abaixo tem uma forma de capturar todos os que se repetem seguindo o código que foi repassado:

```
var repeated = [];

var aux = vetor.filter(function(elemento, i) {
    if(vetor.indexOf(elemento) !== i) {
        repeated.push(elemento)
    }
    return vetor.indexOf(elemento) == i;
})
```

#### O que esse código faz?

O `vetor.indexOf(elemento) !== i` verifica se o elemento ao ser buscado no array é encontrado na mesma posição que está atualmente, caso se tenha algum elemento idêntico a ele na posição do indexOf será diferente e não será retornado no filter.

Quando isso acontece é adicionado no array repeated o elemento repetido.

Answer (score 5):

Para que fique mais fácil de entender, você pode tentar fazer isso em duas operações, primeiro criando o array de elementos repetidos, e depois criando um array com os elementos únicos. Um exemplo de como achar os repetidos:

```
var arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
var sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort(); // Ordenando o array. 
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Um exemplo de como criar um array sem repetições:

```
var arr = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10];

function arrayNovo(arr){
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(tmp.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
        tmp.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

console.log(arrayNovo(arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

Olha não sei que está tentando fazer, queres remove os elementos iguais e jogando eles em outro array mais faz assim.

```
//Criando vetores;
let vetorA = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 11, 7, 1, 11];
console.log('VetorA original ==>',vetorA)
let vetorB = [];


//retirando elementos iguais do vetorA[];
vetorA.forEach((elemem =>{
    if(!vetorB.includes(elemem)){
        vetorB.push(elemem)
    }
}));
/*no código acima eu verifico quais são os elemento repetidos no vetorA
quando encontro um repetido eu coloco ele em outro array, ai você vai ter os valores único de A em B;*/

/*se vc quiser deletar o repetidos, fácil você já tem eles agora é só comparar e dar um pop();*/
vetorA.forEach(elemento =>{
    if(vetorB == elemento){
        vetorA.pop(elemento)
    }
})

// ou

vetorA.forEach(elemento =>{
    if(vetorB.includes(elemento)){
        vetorA.pop(elemento)
    }
})

// ou usa um for aninhado percorrendo os dois;
for(let i=0; i<vetorA.length; i++){
    let tem = false;
    for(let j=0; j<vetorB.length; j++){
        if(vetorA[i] == vetorB[j]){
            tem = true;
        }
    }
    if(!false){
        vetorA.pop(vetorA[i])
    }
}
```

mais como eu disse não entendi o porque de valores iguais depois excluir;