# Retornar elementos repetido dentro de um array

Tags: javascript, array

Como fazer para pegar apenas os elementos repetidos dentro de um array?

Eu tenho por exemplo:

```
let array = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9];
```

E quero retornar todos os duplicados para obter:

```
[2, 3, 4, 8, 9 ]
```

Se eu usasse o `[...new Set(array)]` ele retornaria:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: Bom amigo, você pode usar o `filter` para trazer todos os valores duplicados `const arrayFilter = array.filter((item, index, array) => array.indexOf(item) !== index  // [2,2,3,3,4,4,8,8 ...]` e se quiser trazer apenas um unico valor repetido pode usar o `new Set`  `const duplicates = [...new Set(arrayFilter )]`

Comment: [A resposta está aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376160/capturar-elementos-repetidos-de-um-array-javascript)